# kubetnetes cluster in Azure (AKS) upgrade 1.24.9 in fail state with pods facing intermittent DNS issues

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, coredns

I upgrade AKS using Azure portal from 1.23.5 to 1.24.9. This part finished properly (or so I assumed) based on below status on Azure portal.
[image]

I continued with 1.24.9 to 1.25.5. This time it worked partly. Azure portal shows 1.25.5 for nodepool with provision state "Failed". While nodes are still at 1.24.9.

I found that some nodes were having issues connecting to network including outside e.g. github as well as internal "services". For some reason it is intermittent issue. On same node it sometime works and sometimes not. (I had pods running on each node with python.)

[image]

Each node has cluster IP in resolv.conf
[image]

One of the question on SO had a hint about `ingress-nginx` compatibility. I found that I had an incompatible version. So I upgraded it to [1.6.4 which is compatible with 1.24 and 1.25 both](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)

But this network issue still persists. I am not sure if this is because AKS provisioning state of "Failed". Connectivity check for this cluster in Azure portal is Success. Only issue reported in Azure portal diagnostics is nodepool provisioning state.
[image]

is there anything I need to do after `ingress-nginx` upgrade for all nodes/pods to get the new config?
Or is there a way to re-trigger this upgrade? although I am not sure why, but just assuming that it may reset the configs on all nodes and might work.

Comment: can you try doing: `az aks nodepool upgrade -n agentpool -g rg_name --cluster-name aks_name --node-image-only`? that should update nodes to 1.25.x

Comment: Well, it did trigger the upgrade again. While it is upgrading 2nd image now. I noticed bellow error.   `metrics-server Error: unable to load configmap based request-header-client-ca-file: Get "https://production-dns-23c01f45.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s │
│ .io:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/extension-apiserver-authentication": dial tcp: i/o timeout`

Comment: The same pod also shows `metrics-server-vpa ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I0216 14:41:53.820678       1 pod_nanny.go:189] Failed to read data from config file "/et ││ c/config/NannyConfiguration": open /etc/config/NannyConfiguration: no such file or directory, using default parameters  `

Comment: some of the metrics server errors can be ignored. check after all the nodes are updated

Comment: This upgrade failed. Now 2 nodes are on 1.25.5 and other 3 on 1.24.9. Below is the error message `Code: ReconcileVMSSAgentPoolFailed
Message: Drain of aks-agentpool-31265176-vmss000004 did not complete: Too many req pod metrics-server-8644c8db54-tn8tp on node aks-agentpool-31265176-vmss000004: kube-system/metrics-server-8644c8db54-tn8tp blocked by pdb metrics-server-pdb with unready pods [kube-system/metrics-server-8644c8db54-wdk5w]. See http://aka.ms/aks/debugdrainfailures` I am going to read what are the suggestions on the link

Comment: metrics-server-pdb seems to have 0 allowed disruptions. As per the link and earlier message, this could be the cause. reason could be as pods for metrics-server fails.  as per point 2 in the link above, I deleted pdb, but it imeediately came back. then I tried point 1 to edited this pdb to make "min available" 0 and trigger the upgrade again. But pdb is again back to original with "min available 1" and "allowed disruptions 0". I believe I will now wait for theis upgrade to finish before I can try the 3rd option in

Comment: I also checked that the link from which metrics-server is trying to get the configmap and fails with i/o timeout works from my browser and seems to give appropriate authorization message. So seems like the cluster has networking issues at some common layer and thus cascade errors in every other component ` {
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
}`

Comment: So, now there are 2 nodes left with 1.24.9 version and upgrade still fails. I tried 3rd option from [MS link about drain issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/error-code-poddrainfailure), but the moment I start the upgrade metrics-server deployment comes back again with same pdb state and it blocks the upgrade again. Not sure how to get pass this road block.

Comment: i suggest you open up a support ticket, i dont think its feasible to try and find help on stack overflow given how abnormal the situation looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, posting the solution and journey to it here, so just in case someone comes across similar issue.

There was a network issue in the cluster after the upgrade. This was the reason all pods had DNS issue. Due to these network issues metrics-server was not in running state and it's pdb allowed disruption remained at 0 and it was causing `PodDrainFaulure` errors while upgrading the node.

I was able to force the upgrade to upgrade all nodes to 1.25.5 by running the command `az aks nodepool upgrade -n agentpool -g rg_name --cluster-name aks_name --node-image-only` . However, after executing this, I had to keep on [deleting the pdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/error-code-poddrainfailure) to get all the nodes to upgrade.

This helped to get control plane and all nodes to reach 1.25.5 version, however overall status still remained in failed(Running) state. This was solved by triggering another upgrade with --cluster-plane-only flag

```
   --resource-group <ResourceGroupName> --name <AKSClusterName> \
   --control-plane-only \
   --kubernetes-version <KubernetesVersion>
```

However, this did not solve the core networking issues, as starting from metrics server to application pods, all were failing trying to resolve hostnames. Interesting thing was that internal services were not reachable at all, however outside network e.g. github.com, microsoft.com etc would work intermittently.

Based on [AKS issue 2903](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2903) and related [ingress-nginx issue 8501](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/8501) found that after k8s 1.24 ingress-nginx needs special annotation to keep health probes running properly. had to update helm with below command

```
helm upgrade ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
  --reuse-values \
  --namespace <NAMESPACE> \
  --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz
```

This did get the Azure aks health dashboard and metrics server to show as running state, but it did not solve the underlying network issue. used all the scenarios and commands mentioned in all sections of [MS troubleshooting guide for outbound connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/basic-troubleshooting-outbound-connections) to narrow down that issue is somehow with `kube-dns` service and CoreDNS pods.

as DNS resolution would work if upstreaming nameserver directly to coreDNS pod IP (need to run on the same node) OR public DNS, but it will fail if it was using `kube-dns` service ip as configured in `resolv.conf`

```
jovyan@elyra-web-59f899c447-xw5x2:~$ host -a microsoft.com
Trying "microsoft.com.elyra-airflow.svc.cluster.local"
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

jovyan@elyra-web-59f899c447-xw5x2:~$ nslookup microsoft.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

jovyan@elyra-web-59f899c447-xw5x2:~$ nslookup microsoft.com 1.1.1.1
Server:         1.1.1.1
Address:        1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   microsoft.com
Address: 20.103.85.33
Name:   microsoft.com
Address: 20.112.52.29
Name:   microsoft.com
Address: 20.81.111.85
Name:   microsoft.com
Address: 20.84.181.62
Name:   microsoft.com
Address: 20.53.203.50
```

I restarted coreDNS, konnectivity-agent and so on, but no help.
At the end found a [hint from AKS issue 1320](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1320#issuecomment-555897357) which helped solved the issue. Even though this issue is related to k8s version 1.13 thus suggesting it was not a version specific problem. I deleted ALL pods from namespace `kube-system` at once. Immediately after these pods were up and running, DNS issue was gone and all is working as before.

Phew,  this was some journey of 5 days to get it solved. Looking forward to next upgrade in March now !